# How to get the Approval Status from the workflow history?

Tags: c#, tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to get the approval status for each activity of the workflow process history item as below.

```cs
var status = csClient.Read(activitiydetails.Id, readoption) as ApprovalStatusData;
logdetails("Activity Approval Status--->" + status.Title.ToString());
```

I am getting "object reference error"

Comment: And why do you think you are getting that error?

Comment: got it.  var activityHistory = activitiydetails as ActivityHistoryData; logdetails("Activity Approval Status--->" +activityHistory.ApprovalStatus.Title.ToString());

Comment: Great to hear that you figured it out. In the future I suggest doing as Dominic suggests and not using "as cast" constructs anymore. Since he pinpointed to the casting style, can you accept his answer?

Comment: Thanks Frank - didn't like to ask myself! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `As` operator to cast to `ApprovalStatusData`, you should expect that if the object returned from `csClient.Read()` is not an `ApprovalStatusData`, its value will be null. When you then try to use it on the following line, you will get an object reference error.

It seems likely from the fact that your variable is called `activitiydetails` [sic] that you shouldn't be expecting an `ApprovalStatusData` to be returned.

If you write the code with the correct Cast operator, the code will fail when you try to cast, and throw an InvalidCastException.

```cs
var status = (ApprovalStatusData)csClient.Read(activitiydetails.Id, readoption);
logdetails("Activity Approval Status--->" + status.Title.ToString());
```